# Signup form with multiple steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have few forms that I used to create advertisement for my client website. How do I disable other links until the user fill first form? Please look at my images.

This is the thing I want to achieve. 
[image]

Here is my html code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="post-new-ad-link">
        <a href="#">Post free ad</a>
    </div>

    <div class="other-links">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Basic details</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Images</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-money fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Price</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Location</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Contact and status</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.post-new-ad-link {
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: #53bff7;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
.post-new-ad-link a {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
}
.other-links {
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
.other-links ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.other-links li {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.other-links li a {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    display: block;
    color: #666666;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.other-links li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background:#ddd;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/DTcHh/27144/)

Any jquery option or other one?

Comment: where is your js?

Comment: can you accept my answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Pointer event :none should do the trick. I have modified your HTML and CSS file to achieve the same. You have to write your own logic under what event(completion), the next li should be enabled. At present i have written a logic to enable the second li on the click of first li. To enable the third li you should click second li....

Make sure to add data-disabled attribute to the `<li>` tag.

Refer the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santhoshkumar14/DTcHh/27145/)

Comment: kalaku machi :)

Comment: can we have personal chat? i need ur whatsapp number.. so we can discuss abt our knowledge and working... unga kitta kathukalam nu iruken

Comment: my numb 8489972709